# can a PHP class return a recordset

Tags: php, class, ms-access

I'm trying to create a class for my access database connection and return a recordset, then iterate through the RS with MoveNext().

```
class AccessDBConnection 
{ 
private $db; 
private $sql; 

function __construct($db, $sql) {

    $conn = new COM('ADODB.Connection') or exit('Cannot start ADO.');
    $conn->Open("DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=$db"); 

    $rs = $conn->Execute($sql);
    return $rs;

}
```

USE:

```
function testclass () {
    $rs = new AccessDBConnection("e:\database.mdb", "SELECT StudentID, UserName FROM MyTable WHERE StudentID = 'BJxxxx'");

    while (!$rs->EOF) { 
        $SID =  $rs->Fields['StudentID']->Value; 
        $UN =  $rs->Fields['UserName']->Value;
            echo $SID . " -- CLASS TEST -- " . $UN . "<br>";
                $rs->MoveNext(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: This would be considered bad practice even if it was possible. Maybe what you are looking for is some static scope or singleton approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't return your resultset from constructor.

Create some separated method like `getRS` which will returns it.

```
class AccessDBConnection 
{
    private $conn;

    public function __construct($db) {

        $this->conn = new COM('ADODB.Connection') or exit('Cannot start ADO.');
        $this->conn->Open("DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=$db"); 

    }

    public function query($sql) {

        return $this->conn->Execute($sql);

    }

}
```

Usage:

```
function testclass () {
    $db = new AccessDBConnection("e:\database.mdb");
    $rs = $db->query("SELECT StudentID, UserName FROM MyTable WHERE StudentID = 'BJxxxx'");

    while (!$rs->EOF) { 
        $SID =  $rs->Fields['StudentID']->Value; 
        $UN =  $rs->Fields['UserName']->Value;
            echo $SID . " -- CLASS TEST -- " . $UN . "<br>";
                $rs->MoveNext(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: i wanted to use it more for the connection than the results? I see your point, I would have to return it in an array or something other than a recordset...

Comment: Thanks so much, one issue I'm getting error: PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function Execute() on a non-object in E:\... `return $conn->Execute($sql);`

Answer (score 2):

Constructors do not return. So calling:

```
$rs = new AccessDBConnection($db, $sql);
```

Will not yield a recordset.

Some general pointers:

- Do very little in your `__construct` so as to make testing easier should you come to it
- Create a method akin to `public function connect()` which performs the connection
- Create a method for performing queries and returning a recordset.

Alternatively find an wrapper class that has already done the legwork. No sense in rewriting the wheel.

Comment: finding anything where PHP uses Access Database is a challenge... So your saying I can return a RS, just not in the __construct?

Comment: Correct. You could essentially build your own version oh the `mysql_` functions. A quick Google turned up a couple of results, you could base yours on what's available.